# How do I figure out when the fingerprint (Touch ID) and password were changed on my MacBook Air using Terminal?

Tags: macos, login, terminal.app

I am on macOS Big Sur and trying to figure out when my TouchID and password were changed on my MacBook Air.

Is there a command I can type in Terminal I can use to find this information? I am trying to search back about 2 months when it was changed and see the exact date and time this happened.